# How to separate a char and a value in input? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have an input that looks something like this:
value = '35C, 22.4C, 12.8C'

I want to separate it so that it looks like the following:
list = ['35', '22.4', '12.8']

Thank you. :)

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> value.replace('C', '').split(',')
['35', '22.4', '12.8']
```

OR

```
>>> re.findall('[0-9.]+', value)
['35', '22.4', '12.8']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '35C, 22.4C, 12.8C'
items = data.replace('C', '').replace(',', '').split()
print(items)
```

First replace C from the string and then replace the `,` then split. Now you get the list containing only numbers.

Output:

```
['35', '22.4', '12.8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best in performance, but flexible to some string formatting differences like

```
value = '35 T, 22.4C , 12.8 ABC ';
```

Using regular expression:

```
import re

value = '35C, 22.4C, 12.8C';

result = re.split(r'[^0-9]+\s*,\s', value)
result[-1] = re.sub(r'([0-9])[^0-9]+\s*$', r'\1', result[-1])
print(result)
```